# MYSQL Brands list order by product count but

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, distinct

i have two table. Like this;

---

```
Products table

id | brand | bla bla bla
```

---

```
Priority table

id | brand
```

---

I am listing to SELECT DISTINCT brand FROM Products table BY ORDERING product COUNT like this;

```
SELECT DISTINCT brand as bra, (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM Products WHERE brand = bra) as cnt FROM Products ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Result is:

1. A Brand (65 products)
2. B Brand (43 products)
3. C Brand (23 products)
4. D Brand (17 products)

This is a perfect working line. But i want to give priority to some brands. For top of listing.

Like this:

1. S Brand (22 products)
2. X Brand (4 products)
3. A Brand (65 products)
4. B Brand (43 products)
5. C Brand (23 products)
6. D Brand (17 products)

I used this line. But it didn't work.

```
SELECT DISTINCT brand as bra, (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM Products WHERE brand = bra) as cnt, , (SELECT brand FROM Priority) as prior FROM Products ORDER BY prior ASC,cnt DESC
```

What is true line? Thanks...

---EDIT---
FULL ANSWER IS:

```
SELECT p.brand as bra, count(p.id) as cnt
FROM products p
GROUP BY bra
ORDER BY bra IN (SELECT pri.brand FROM priority pri ORDER BY pri.brand ASC) DESC, mark ASC
```

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
ORDER BY bra IN (SELECT brand FROM Priority) DESC, cnt DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first query is more clearly written as:

```
SELECT b.brand as bra, count(p.id) as cnt
FROM bra b left outer join
     Products p
     on b.brand = p.brand
GROUP BY b.bra
ORDER BY cnt DESC;
```

The `left outer join` is only needed if you are concerned about non-matching records.  If that is not a concern, an easier way to write the query is:

```
SELECT p.brand as bra, count(p.id) as cnt
FROM Products p
GROUP BY p.bra
ORDER BY cnt DESC;
```

If you want to order by priority, just join that in.  This may be what you want:

```
SELECT p.brand as bra, count(p.id) as cnt
FROM bra b left outer join
     Products p
     on b.brand = p.brand left outer join
     Priority pr
     on b.brand = pr.brand
GROUP BY b.bra
ORDER BY pr.brand is not null desc, cnt DESC;
```

This will put the brands in the priority table first.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But p.bra is giving error in GROUP BY. "Unknown column 'p.bra' in 'group statement'"